# is there a limit to the number of functions that can consume anchor Context?

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, anchor-test

I currently Have four functions, that consume the context for my `Dummy` Accounts struct, Two of the functions work as expected but the other two fail.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct Dummy<'info> {
    /// CHECK - We are setting this up ourselves
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub auth: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"BOCCHI"],
        bump,
        init_if_needed,
        space = PROTOCOL_STATE_SPACE,
        payer = signer
    )]
    pub data: Box<Account<'info, DataAccount>>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn dummy_one(ctx: Context<Dummy>, var_one: u32) -> Result<()> {

 Ok(())
} 

pub fn dummy_two(ctx: Context<Dummy>, var_two: u64) -> Result<()> {

 Ok(())
} 

pub fn dummy_three(ctx: Context<Dummy>) -> Result<()> {

 Ok(())
} 

pub fn dummy_four(ctx: Context<Dummy>) -> Result<()> {
 
 Ok(())
}
```

When I try to run functions `dummy_three` and `dummy_four`, I get the following error

```
AnchorError: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.
    at Function.parse (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/nft/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:135:14)
    at translateError (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/nft/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:276:35)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/nft/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errorLogs: [
    'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.'
  ],
  logs: [
    'Program C3N7mj1oCrQNkzLW3dcaV7FrSbqJjbRX6BKkXePz2tFG invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: DummyFour',
    'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.',
    'Program C3N7mj1oCrQNkzLW3dcaV7FrSbqJjbRX6BKkXePz2tFG consumed 3292 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program C3N7mj1oCrQNkzLW3dcaV7FrSbqJjbRX6BKkXePz2tFG failed: custom program error: 0x66'
  ],
  error: {
    errorCode: { code: 'InstructionDidNotDeserialize', number: 102 },
    errorMessage: 'The program could not deserialize the given instruction',
    comparedValues: undefined,
    origin: undefined
  },
  _programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack { stack: [ [PublicKey] ] }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error has nothing to do with the context. You can use the same context in as many ixs as you like.

The error here states that the program can't deserialize the instruction which means that the instruction has been wrongly serialised.

This usually happens when the IDL isn't updated after the changes have been made to the program. But in your case, I am guessing that the problem arises due to the wrong argument passed in the third and fourth ixs on the client-side. The first two instructions have the arguments of type `u64` and `u32`. I think you have copied the same statement for the last two ixs without removing the argument.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is not because of a limit on the number of functions but due to this: `#[instruction(bump: u8)]`.

Passing the instruction’s arguments with the `#[instruction(..)]` attribute makes anchor look for those arguments in the instruction's data.

I am not sure 100%, but I think it fails on `dummy_three` and `dummy_four` because it's trying to deserialize the instruction data and since those two instruction have no arguments it fails and throws the error `InstructionDidNotDeserialize`. But doesn't fail on `dummy_one` and `dummy_two` because while they don't have the `bump` argument, at least they have other arguments which make up a valid instruction data for anchor to deserialize.

Whatever the reason is, if you remove `#[instruction(bump: u8)]` your problem will be gone, it's redundant anyway since none of your instructions have an argument named `bump`, nor are you using it anywhere in your Account's constraints.